# how to convert hexadecimal byte value to decimal in c#

Tags: c#

I have a c# appliaction in which i used byte array on it. If i try to get the length of the array i got it as hexa decimal value like "0x0A". I did lot of conversion to convert it as decimal format but im not able to convert into decimal format.Pls refer my code below and guide me,

```
byte a[] = {0x0A , 0x01 , 0x02 , 0x03 , 0x04 , 0x05 , 0x06 , 0x07 , 0x09 , 0x01};
byte b=a.Length; //now i get b length as 0x0A
```

i tried to convert using integer values also but it not working

Comment: Why are you using `byte b = a.Length`? Why didn't you use `int b` or `var b`?

Comment: Are you saying that Visual Studio shows the length as 0x0A when you hover over `a.Length` in the editor?

Comment: Your code does not even compile. I changed it to byte[] a = { 0x0A, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x09, 0x01 };
            int b = a.Length; and it returns b = 10 as expected.

Comment: Are you sure this is C#? Array declaration (`[]`) must be placed after the type (`byte`), not the identifier (`a`). This isn't C...

Comment: How did you even compile that?
you should declare array as `byte[] a`, and you can't just assign `int` to `byte`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option in the Visual Studio debugger to show all integral values – including `byte` – in hexadecimal.

Right click in one of the debugger display windows (like Locals or Watch) and unselect Hexadecimal Display in the content menu.